# Array count for numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmediaitem

I'm grabbing music albums from the phone's music library.  I want to put the albums in sections (with the album cover as the section header image) and then the albums songs will fill in each sections table.

I know how to get an array of albums, which will be used for `numberOfSectionsInTableView`.

**But I'm not sure how the array of album tracks works for `numberOfRowsInSection`**.  Because I essentially need to navigate into the array of albums and then navigate inside of each album, which is two levels deep.

Can anyone help me with this?

`**AlbumsTableViewController.h**`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Albums *albumsFromClass = [[Albums alloc] init];
    albumsArrayForTVC = [albumsFromClass getAlbumsArray];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return albumsArrayForTVC.count;
}
```

`**Albums.h**`

```
- (NSArray *)getAlbumsArray {
    _albumsMPMediaQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    _albumsArray = [_albumsMPMediaQuery collections];
    return _albumsArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the array of albums, or the first object in the array, to see how the data is structured.  Assuming it is nested arrays, albumsArrayForTVC[0] should grab an array of songs for a specific album.  You can save this as a variable or do something like albumsArrayForTVC[0][2] to grab the third song in the first album.